# could not convert string to float: '7,751.30'

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, types

I get the TWSE price from Taiwan Stock Exchange.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Stock\TWSE.csv',encoding='Big5')
df.head()
    日期    開盤指數   最高指數   最低指數   收盤指數
0 96/02/01 7,751.30  7,757.63   7,679.78  7,701.54
1 96/02/02 7,754.16  7,801.63   7,751.53  7,777.03
2 96/02/05 7,786.77  7,823.94   7,772.05  7,783.12
3 96/02/06 7,816.30  7,875.75   7,802.94  7,875.75
4 96/02/07 7,894.77  7,894.77   7,850.06  7,850.06
```

```
df.loc[0][2]
'7,757.63'

type(df.loc[0][2])
str
```

I want to convert the str type to float type for the purpose of plotting.
But, I can not convert them. For example:

```
float(df.loc[0][2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7,757.63'
```

Comment: Get rid of the comma

Comment: You can't do it with the comma in the string. Remove comma, then it should convert fine.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Stock\TWSE.csv',encoding='Big5', thousands=',')`. The read functions have a `thousands` argument you should exploit for this.

Comment: @Abdou Ah, I knew about this, but missed it. Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

`pd.read_csv`, much like almost every other `pd.read_*` function, has a `thousands` parameter you can set to `','` to make sure that you're importing those values as floats.

The following is an illustration:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


txt = '日期    開盤指數   最高指數   最低指數   收盤指數\n0 96/02/01 7,751.30  7,757.63   7,679.78  7,701.54\n1 96/02/02 7,754.16  7,801.63   7,751.53  7,777.03\n2 96/02/05 7,786.77  7,823.94   7,772.05  7,783.12\n3 96/02/06 7,816.30  7,875.75   7,802.94  7,875.75\n4 96/02/07 7,894.77  7,894.77   7,850.06  7,850.06'

with io.StringIO(txt) as f:
    df = pd.read_table(f, encoding='utf8', header=0, thousands=',', sep='\s+')

print(df)
```

Yields:

```
   日期     開盤指數     最高指數  最低指數  收盤指數
0  96/02/01  7751.30  7757.63  7679.78  7701.54
1  96/02/02  7754.16  7801.63  7751.53  7777.03
2  96/02/05  7786.77  7823.94  7772.05  7783.12
3  96/02/06  7816.30  7875.75  7802.94  7875.75
4  96/02/07  7894.77  7894.77  7850.06  7850.06
```

I hope this proves helpful.

Comment: Thank you! it works. And, I think it is really efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
float(df.loc[0][2].replace(',',''))
```

Comment: Thank you, Shiva. It works!
I want to convert all number data to float type.
Is there any fast solution?

Comment: np, if possible make it as correct answer, it might helpfull for some one :)

Comment: This is a pretty poor answer, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: put this code in forloop..

Comment: That's the worst possible solution for a pandas question... using a loop.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for the comments.. am not into pandas.. i have given my input.

Comment: OK, I use for loop to complete it. It works.
But I will use 'thousands' in read_csv function.
Thank you!!!